# flutter googlemap get address

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to fetch address to show on google map. I can only do address with lat,lng. Name of home address, road, sub-district, city, but I tried many ways and it's not showing up. Please help.

I'll have it written in the else section.

```
 @override
void initState() {
findLocation();
super.initState();
}

LatLng centerMap = LatLng(1232,213123, 123.123213);

void findLocation() async {
  var lat = double.tryParse(searchitems[0].address![widget.index].latitude.toString());
   var lng = double.tryParse(searchitems[0].address![widget.index].longitude.toString());

if (lat != null && lng != null) {
  centerMap = LatLng(lat, lng);
} else {

  
}
print("map:$centerMap");
}
```

Comment: So you want to fetch address by lat lang or you want to find address by text ?

Comment: I want to fetch both. I fetch with lat,lng. But some address don't have lat,lng input. So if any address don't have lat,lng find by address name.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get address by `lattiude` and `longitude` then you can use Google's API for finding the address.

For that, first you have to generate a key from `Google Cloud Platform` and enable the Geocoding API from it. Then you can fetch `address` this way:

```js
getAddressFromLatLng(context, double lat, double lng) async {
    String _host = 'https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json';
    final url = '$_host?key=$mapApiKey&language=en&latlng=$lat,$lng';
    if(lat != null && lng != null){
      var response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
      if(response.statusCode == 200) {
        Map data = jsonDecode(response.body);
        String _formattedAddress = data["results"][0]["formatted_address"];
        print("response ==== $_formattedAddress");
        return _formattedAddress;
      } else return null;
    } else return null;
  }
```

Now if you want to get `lat-long` by address, you can do it in following way. You can add this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoder) called `geocoder`:

(from source)

```js
import 'package:geocoder/geocoder.dart';

// From a query
final query = "1600 Amphiteatre Parkway, Mountain View";
var addresses = await Geocoder.local.findAddressesFromQuery(query);
var first = addresses.first;
print("${first.featureName} : ${first.coordinates}");
```

There's also a package called `geocoding`([link](https://pub.dev/packages/geocoding)). You can try that too.